# How to create an Add to Cart button to add multiple products

Tags: php, magento

I need to create an "add to cart" button in my upsell.phtml file to add two or more products to the cart.

I have the id of those products and now i had to add them to the cart with a single "add to cart" button, quantity is always be 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I bet it would be easier for you to go with the free extension for your magento cms, with this one: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/add-multiple-products-to-cart.html

Comment: I dont want to show multiple "add to cart" button, just one button to do the job.

Comment: Well I have done this Thanks all for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this code

```
<?php $productids = $_POST['prod_ids']; ?>
<?php foreach($productids as $productid): ?>
    <?php $my_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid); ?>
    <?php $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart'); ?>
    <?php $cart->init(); ?>
    <?php $cart->addProduct($my_product, array('qty' => 1)); ?>
    <?php $cart->save(); ?>
    <?php Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Pradeep for your reply.
I am using this code for adding the button 
""<input type="button" value="Add To Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_Product) ?>')"/>""
But when I use this it only add one product to the cart. How can I pass the whole values with this.

Comment: you can use ajax and send the ids of the products which you want to add to cart

Comment: I am a newbie programmer, just beginner and I am not good at ajax right now. that's why I am using functions to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

1. On "Add to cart" button call a javaScript function say "FnAddToCart()"
2. From "FnAddToCart()" send a ajax request to server. Along with request send the ids to add.
3. In the server persist the data to the cart. You can do this in database of your choice.

Comment: Good Answer Falaque Aunty, wonder no one has upvoted. I have upvoted.